# Swagger UI does not show all the controllers of my project

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have few controllers which have the same request path prefix i.e.

```
/v4/users/{userId}/
```

And then the methods in the controllers are annotated with separate path mappings. The swagger ui shows only one of those controllers.

```
@Component
public class BaseController {

}

/******************/

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v4/users/{userId}/payment")
public class PaymentController extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/initiate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public HttpEntity<Object> initiatePayment() {...}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/success", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public HttpEntity<Object> success() {...} 
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v4/users/{userId}/preferences")
public class CustomerPreferencesController extends BaseController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deals/{dealId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public HttpEntity<Object> favouriteDeal(...) {...}

    //some more methods

}
```

There is one more controller that has the same path prefix i.e. **/v4/users/{userId}** which shows up on swagger-ui but not the above two controllers.

**pom.xml** entries:

```
    <!-- Swagger Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**UPDATE - 1**

```
@Bean
public Docket mobileAPI() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .host(swaggerHost)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .pathMapping("/");
}
```

Comment: Can you share your Springfox configuration? I guess there's something with the regex in the paths section of your `Docket` configuration.

Comment: @g00glen00b I have updated the answer. I have added the bean for my swagger configuration.

Comment: Can you tell me what Swagger version you're using? I copied your code in a new project, added the `@EnableSwagger2` annotation, replace the `${swagger.version}` by 2.5.0 and it all works. https://i.imgur.com/6HFv3Db.png

Comment: My Swagger version is 2.5.0
`<swagger.version>2.5.0</swagger.version>`

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using Swagger 2.5.0 for springfox-swagger-ui? Nonetheless, I cannot reproduce your issue with the code you provided. You're sure you have the `@EnableSwagger2` annotation somewhere, right?